# LinQ ofType in Value

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string,object> Items;
```

Now I need to get all Items where the **Value** of the Dictionary-item is from a specific type. (e.g. "int")

`var intValues = Items.OfType<KeyValuePair<string,int>>` simply does not work.

Code without LinQ would be something like:

```
var intValues=new Dictionary<string,int>()
foreach (var oldVal in Items) {
  if (oldVal.Value is int) {
    intValues.add(oldVal.Key, oldVal.Value);
  }
}
```

(Update) my example should show the basic idea. But if possible I would avoid to create a new Dictionary as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `is` operator on the `Value` property:

```
var intValues = Items.Where(x => x.Value is int);
```

If you want an actual `Dictionary<string,int>` at the end just add:

```
.ToDictionary(v=> v.Key, v=> (int)v.Value)
```

Answer (score 7):

The direct translation of your `foreach` would be the following in LINQ:

```
var intValues = Items.Where(item => item.Value is int)
                     .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => (int)item.Value);
```

So basically, you filter first for where the `item.Value` is an `int`, and then you create a dictionary from it using [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) where you cast those values to `int` to make sure that the resulting dictionary is a `Dictionary<string, int>`. Since we filtered non-integers already, this type cast will always succeed.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this:

```
var intValue = Items
    .Where(x => x.Value is int) // filter per Value is int
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => (int)x.Value); // create a new dictionary converting Value to int
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
var result = Items.Where(x => x.Value is int)
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```